# Is it possible to run a program (java\c\etc) under these situations?

Tags: java, c, esx

Scenario 1: I have a test server that gets OS reinstalls on a frequent basis. Is there any way to add a program to the server that will remain and execute even if the OS is reinstalled? (I know it's a stretch, but had to ask)

Scenario 2: I have another server running ESXi 5.1 (which I admit, I know nothing about) how (or can) I run a program at the OS level (not as a VM)? Reason being, I need to get information specific to the server and not the VM's such as ip,MAC address, etc that my program gathers with Runtime.exec().

I have a PXE server setup with kickstart files that work great for linux, but not sure if I can do it with ESX or not, anyone ever try to PXE boot ESX like this? On linux, I run my program via crontab, and in the past did it with rc.local. Any suggestions would be appreciated, even if it is a link to potential resources you have had luck with in similar situations.

Comment: How is this a java or c question? Sounds like a question about VM management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)   The program must run within an OS, or the JVM will have been designed to run without an OS.  I don't believe there is a JVM which will use an OS if it is there but not care if it is not.

You can do this with virtual machines. You can have the OS run/stop/start/reinstall in a virtual machine, while an application is running on the bare machine or in another virtual machine.

2) When you application runs, it is at the OS level.  The distinction is largely an illusion.  You can get the IP and MAC addresses in normal Java. If you nee to get something else, you can use JNA/JNI/JNR.

I have not heard of ESX before.